# Getting temperature from pixel data

Tags: image, matlab, pixel, analysis

I have a color picture from an infrared camera. It is temperature levels in different color. 
I want to transfer the temperature data from this picture over a 3D model. 
My problem is to find a correlation between pixel data (u, v, color,..) and temperature level. I use Matlab for this purpose. Please let me know if you have any idea to solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe the discussion from here http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/25204-how-to-find-the-temperature-of-the-image will help you get more info about what additional data you need before getting to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the first dimension of your RGB image, the red component:
Red = I(:,:,1);
The intensity values of the Red component should correlate well to the temperature level.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is that possible for color picture for every format (JPEG, PNG,...) or it should be in special format?

Comment: No need for a special format. However, there are different color-space representations that you can work with, see here [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space)

Answer (score 0):

Following what Leeor said:

If you load a picture (as jpg, png...) you'll have a matrix of dimensions height x width x 3

This "3" dimensions are the RGB values.

In this way, you will know what color you have.

To know what temperature it corresponds, you need to have a reference data. For example, if you have a color bar that shows the colours corresponding to a temperature range of 500 to 1500 ºC, for instance, you can try to find the closest value of your pixel color of the image to the pixel color of the colorbar.